# Read JSON file from assets

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to read a JSON file from assets in fragment using `getAssets()`, but the IDE says "can not resolve this method (getAssets())".

**Code**

```
 public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("moods.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Create a class **LoaderHelper.java**

```
public class LoaderHelper {
    public static String getJson(Context context, String json){
        String jsonString=parseFileToString(context, json);
        return jsonString;
    }
    public static String parseFileToString( Context context, String filename )
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open( filename );
            int size = stream.available();

            byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
            stream.read(bytes);
            stream.close();

            return new String( bytes );

        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            Log.i("GuiFormData", "IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

To get the **json string** call the above class as:

```
String str=LoaderHelper.parseFileToString(context, "levels.json");
```

where **levels.json** is the json file stored in `asset` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Method `getAssets()` is part of Context class. So if you're not calling `loadJSONFromAsset()` in the class that extends Context, e.g. Activity, you need to provide reference to Context as an argument to your method and then call `getAssets()` on it